# cannot get [(ngModel)] value to use in component Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, primeng, angular-ngmodel

in html file, using ngModel which i want to get its value to use in my component

**edit-customer.component.html**

```
  <input id="userInfoEmail" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{userInfo.email}}" [(ngModel)]="userInfo.email" disabled>
```

since its two way binding, i had use it im my component as follows,

**edit-customer.component.ts**

```
checkUserEmail(): void {
    this.userInfo.email = this.userEmail;
    this.customerService.checkEmail(this.userEmail).subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.twoFactorEnabled === true) {
            this.isButtonDisabled = false;
        }
        else {
            this.isButtonDisabled = true;
        }
    })
}
```

also I had declared `this.userEmail:string;`, but unfortunately got error 'undefined' on my console, I read that i need to initialize the object but cant figure it out,

Comment: you dont need the `value="{{userInfo.email}}"` if you have the `[(ngModel)]`, also, have you declared `userInfo:string = "";` in the component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use value with ngModel, remove it first,

```
  <input id="userInfoEmail" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userInfo.email" disabled>
```

now you should be able to access the value in controller like,

```
console.log(this.userInfo.email);
```

whereas userInfo should be defiend at the top as,

**`userInfo: any = {};`** if you have a type change any with type

Answer (score 0):

you can also did that

in ts file make a function

```
  get_coin_current_market_value(symbol){
console.log('symbol is ',symbol);
```

}

and in html

```
 <select class="form-control" name="coin" [(ngModel)]="symbol" 
        (ngModelChange)="get_coin_current_market_value(symbol)">
        <option *ngFor="let coin of allCoinsArray">
               {{ coin.symbol }}
         </option>
 </select>
```